# Match domain including www using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i am trying to match all the domain including `www` using regex and replacing with `preg_replace`

Like

```
$oldomain = "example.com";
$newdomain = "www.example.net";
$string = "example.com, www.example.com, something.example.com, test.example.net, bla bla bla https://example.com etc etc"

preg_replace("#(www.?).#".$oldomain, $newdomain, $string);
```

So it will search for `example.com` and `www.example.com` and it will replace that with `www.example.net`

```
example.com -> www.example.net
www.example.com -> www.example.net
```

Update :

`(www.?)*example.com` - https://regex101.com/r/zOQBQD/1

Comment: @user3783243 i have already described my issues. i want to replace all old domain with new domain with or without www.

Comment: @user3783243 `." . $oldomain . '.#'` this will match both www and non www old domain?

Comment: @user3783243 your asking about string? `$string`. it is a string of web page.

Comment: @user3783243 i have updated the example string and also a regex URL where i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is a special character in regex meaning any single character, excluding new lines. That needs to be escaped or in a character class.

`#` is your delimiter so your regex must be inside both of those.

`*` is a quantifier meaning the preceding character/group can occur zero or more times

You probably want something close to this:

```
preg_replace("#(www[.])?{$oldomain}#", $newdomain, $string);
```

`{$oldomain}` also is not regex, that is PHP syntax for the variable in double quotes to be expanded. Could also be written as:

```
preg_replace('#(www[.])?' . $oldomain . '#', $newdomain, $string);
```

You actually also should escape the domain for special chars so:

```
preg_replace('#(www[.])?' . preg_quote($oldomain, '#') . '#', $newdomain, $string);
```

is likely what you'll really want.

Regex101 as well: https://regex101.com/r/gwxyw1/1

Comment: Yes, you got my point. this work. Thanks for code and explanation

Comment: @Mèrebaiseur It took a few readings to identify it. In the future you should be as detailed as you can in the question. Some users will just downvote question and move on when unclear.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again :)

Comment: From all of 3 PHP code, none of them are working : https://3v4l.org/oC0Mt

Comment: Is the syntax error in your real code?